# How to convert column names and the different values under it into key value pairs in R?

Tags: r, json, data-wrangling

I have a data.frame in R which is in long format.

| Gender | Area | Value | Year | Column X | Column Y | And other columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | urban | 31.45 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| male | rural | 41 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| male | rural | 35.6 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| female | rural | 30 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| female | urban | 21 | 2016 | xxx | yyy | zzz |
| female | rural | 19 | 2016 | xxx | yyy | zzz |

The main aim is to add a new column, say **seg** to this data.frame whose rows are filled in the following format:

| Gender | Area | Value | Year | Column X | Column Y | And other columns... | **seg** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| male | urban | 31.45 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "male", "Area": "urban", "Year": 2012} |
| male | rural | 41 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "male", "Area": "rural", "Year": 2012} |
| male | rural | 35.6 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "male", "Area": "rural", "Year": 2012} |
| female | rural | 30 | 2012 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "female", "Area": "rural", "Year": 2012} |
| female | urban | 21 | 2016 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "female", "Area": "urban", "Year": 2016} |
| female | rural | 19 | 2016 | xxx | yyy | zzz | {"Gender": "female", "Area": "rural", "Year": 2016} |

The format of the contents of the **seg** column is important because it will be fed to a database.

Can anyone advise me how exactly to proceed with that in R? I have spent quite sometime looking around for solutions and couldn't find anything that takes column names, row values in a data.frame and converts them into json strings. The manipulation is not on all the columns but only for specific columns.

Appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `toJSON` from `jsonlite`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
out <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(seg = pmap_chr(select(cur_data(), Gender, Area, Year), ~ 
          toJSON(list(...), auto_unbox = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
out
  Gender  Area Value Year ColumnX ColumnY                                            seg
1   male urban 31.45 2012     xxx     yyy   {"Gender":"male","Area":"urban","Year":2012}
2   male rural 41.00 2012     xxx     yyy   {"Gender":"male","Area":"rural","Year":2012}
3   male rural 35.60 2012     xxx     yyy   {"Gender":"male","Area":"rural","Year":2012}
4 female rural 30.00 2012     xxx     yyy {"Gender":"female","Area":"rural","Year":2012}
5 female urban 21.00 2016     xxx     yyy {"Gender":"female","Area":"urban","Year":2016}
6 female rural 19.00 2016     xxx     yyy {"Gender":"female","Area":"rural","Year":2016}
```

---

Or may use `rowwise`

```
df1 %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(seg = toJSON(lst(Gender, Area, Year), auto_unbox = TRUE)) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Gender Area  Value  Year ColumnX ColumnY seg                                           
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr>   <chr>   <json>                                        
1 male   urban  31.4  2012 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"male","Area":"urban","Year":2012}  
2 male   rural  41    2012 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"male","Area":"rural","Year":2012}  
3 male   rural  35.6  2012 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"male","Area":"rural","Year":2012}  
4 female rural  30    2012 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"female","Area":"rural","Year":2012}
5 female urban  21    2016 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"female","Area":"urban","Year":2016}
6 female rural  19    2016 xxx     yyy     {"Gender":"female","Area":"rural","Year":2016}
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gender = c("male", "male", "male", "female", "female", 
"female"), Area = c("urban", "rural", "rural", "rural", "urban", 
"rural"), Value = c(31.45, 41, 35.6, 30, 21, 19), Year = c(2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2016L, 2016L), ColumnX = c("xxx", "xxx", 
"xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"), ColumnY = c("yyy", "yyy", "yyy", 
"yyy", "yyy", "yyy")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

pmap_dfr(your_data, \(...) {
  tibble::tibble(..., seg = imap(list(...), ~ sprintf("\"%s\": \"%s\"",
                                                      .y, .x)) %>%
                              paste(collapse = ", ") %>%
                              sprintf("{%s}", .))
})
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  Gender Area  Value  Year Column.X Column.Y And.other.column… seg              
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             <chr>            
1 male   urban  31.4  2012 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
2 male   rural  41    2012 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
3 male   rural  35.6  2012 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
4 female rural  30    2012 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
5 female urban  21    2016 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
6 female rural  19    2016 xxx      yyy      zzz               "{\"Gender\": \"…
```

(Data used:)

```
your_data <- structure(list(Gender = c("male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female"), Area = c("urban", "rural", "rural", "rural", "urban", "rural"), Value = c(31.45, 41, 35.6, 30, 21, 19), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2016L, 2016L), Column.X = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"), Column.Y = c("yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy", "yyy"), And.other.columns... = c("zzz", "zzz", "zzz", "zzz", "zzz", "zzz")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```